# Is this a weird or very problematic shared neutral?

Tags: electrical, neutral, mwbc

I will try to explain it and I made a drawing that give an idea of what it seems to look like.

I just had some work done on my house (built in 1967) and the electrician found this weird connection.

I have a 14/3 wire going to an outlet in the kitchen, it was not a GCFI, now it is. In the outlet, I have 2 wires coming in, one from the panel (14/3) and one from the range hood (14/2) (the hood is not installed right now). The range hood has 2 hot black wires on 2 different breaker. The other breaker (the 14/2) is feeding a lot of lights and a microwave.

It seems that somewhere in the wiring the neutral doesn't follow the black, it feeds another set of lights, including the microwave.

In the picture below, the left side is where the microwave / hood are.

We have confirmed that the neutral from the left side is needed to be connected to the neutral from the 14/3 wire, if we remove the connection nothing is working on that side.

The electrician said that it would be a good idea to remove that connection between the 14/3 and 14/2 neutral but that would cost a lot. He also said that since it's working it should be OK to keep it as-is but he said that if I'm selling the house in the future, I should mention this since it could be classified as a latent defect

My question are:

- Is this a dangerous way of connecting everything, is it a latent defect?
- Should the 14/2 also be connected at the panel like the 14/3 is?  (see picture pf the breaker)
- When I install the range hood, which hot wire should I use? the one from the 14/3 or 14/2? (I don't remember how it was connected when I removed it)

[image]

Comment: This looks to be quite a mess - if that picture is real (and not just a random similar picture you found) then you have a fake handle tie on an MWBC, but only 1/2 used (sort of) and in general a real **mess**. I think pictures showing the actual wiring at the breaker, at the GFCI, at the first receptacle past the GFCI, the last receptacle of the left neutral chain and the first receptacle past the breaker of the right neutral chain would help. OMG!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, that is my own drawing with the way i understand how thing are connected

Comment: I know it is your drawing. I am asking for pictures of some of the junction boxes, plus asking if the *breaker picture* is a real picture or just "something you found that looks about the same" - the reason is that the copper-wire-as-handle-tie is very much not code compliant.

Comment: if there are any junction box, they are buried under the attic insulation, so no picture. and yes, this is my own picture from my own panel / breaker

Comment: By junction box, I mean each of those squares with wires that I assume has a receptacle in it.

Comment: @Fredou -- can you find the junction box where the left-side neutral terminates?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel i think this is where thing can get complicated,it might be buried under insulation in the attic. the attic seem to have about 15-20 inchs of blow-in insulation

Comment: @Fredou -- it should bloody well be accessible from below (either through a light fixture, or a blank cover); if not, that's an issue in and of itself

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. based on my experience with this house, the chance of being "easily" accessible is very, very low. this is why if i have to fix this, it can get costly. sadly i can't seem to be able to go in the attic myself, i think some kind of claustrophobia. so i would need to ask someone else to go dig into that insulation and hopefully find where things are connected. sadly in the basement i had many many many many case of hidden junction box behind drywall. the work that i'm talking in the OP is basement cleanup. ($$$$)

Comment: @Fredou To clarify a bit, *normally* a junction box with a receptacle is accessible from the receptacle - i.e., remove the receptacle and you can get to all the wires. I am working under the assumption all the boxes you drew with wires were based on there being receptacles (or hardwired devices like lights) where you have traced the wires to those boxes. If the back on the box is in the attic, that doesn't matter (except if you actually have to replace the entire box). So the question is: If you can't get to the attic *and* the boxes are in the attic, how did you make the wiring diagram?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact each box represent a light fixture/switch/outlet/etc, it's just to show that there are many things connected together. the way i was able to draw the diagram is by turning the breaks off and on and disconnecting and connecting the neutral in the range hood (so the 14/3 and 14/2 are connected or not) and actually seeing what was working and what wasn't.

Comment: Then there should be **no need to go into the attic**, unless there are **additional** boxes up there. Every box you have found already - light, switch, outlet, etc. - is accessible, *by definition*, by removing the cover plate, light, switch, outlet, etc. You will only need to go into the attic if there is a need to run **new wires**, which hopefully won't be necessary, though we don't know for sure yet.

Comment: Turn off all 4 of the breakers in your picture. Remove the cover plate from each outlet, switch or hard-wired device (light, etc) in your drawing. Remove each device (switch/outlet), but DO NOT REMOVE ANY WIRES OR WIRE NUTS. Take a clear, focused picture of each device showing the wires attached to the device & where they run into the box. [Edit] your post to embed each of the pics, numbered to match your drawing. Do this _especially_ for the top center where you show a black from 2 breakers connected in the box. Do not go into the attic for this.

Comment: @FreeMan, i think what i have upstair is the same issue as the basement, each light and switch and the microwave outlet only have 1 wire in them, in the basement i had what the electrician called, octopus junction box where i had 1 hot wire coming and and 7 wire coming out to send power out, i even had one with 1 in and 9 out. i'm pretty sure this is what i have somewhere in my attic. what a mess. i need to find that or these box. if i can find the box, hopefully i can reconnect the neutral that is not connected and at least fix the neutral mess also the breaker on the far left is fine, so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code requires 2 things: First that all junction boxes be accessible, and second that wire splices happen only inside junction boxes.  That is why everyone is expecting this should be accessible.

So there are 2 big problems.  First that breaker's handle-tie is completely hork-a-dork (credit for *having* a handle-tie, but they should've gotten a proper one). Either obtain the proper handle-tie for that breaker, or replace the 2 breakers with a quadplex 15-15-15.

The far bigger problem is this violates a cardinal rule: Neutrals and hots must travel together and Neutrals must serve only their partner hots.  Any outlet must use the neutral from the same cable the hot came from.  You can't loopy-doop neutrals like this for two reasons:  Aside from current imbalance (which causes heating, this is AC power not DC!!!!) the big problem is we could overload the neutral.  Imagine a 15A load plugged into the GFCI, so 15A on the red wire. No problem, right?  Now imagine 2 boxes above it, 15A plugged in there.  What's the current on the /3 white wire?  You're darn right it's 30A!!!!  So this won't do at all.

Now, a "CABLE" contains a number of WIRES inside a sheath.  They don't sell cables with just a black wire, so there must be an undrawn white wire at top center.

Usually when "the last guy" does a dumb thing like this, it's to try to compensate for what is *thought to be* a broken wire.  Often it turns out to not be a broken wire at all, but some sort of blunder.  (remember anyone who does this is NOT the sharpest tool in the shed). Actual wire breaks are VERY rare.

So your task here is to complete the mapping of this circuit, account for every wire, and validate every wire to see what's really broken and what's merely a faulty wire connection at the device (notably: backstabs).

Then, you pick 1 place to break BOTH the black AND white wires: Just left of center where you did not draw a white wire, or above the GFCI.  At that junction box, you disconnect one set and cap them off.

If all wires prove out good, and one of the possible break points is a 2-gang box with 2 yokes (4 sockets), feel free to feed one yoke with one circuit, and the other yoke with the other circuit.  Do NOT split the 2 sockets on one yoke and feed 1 from each circuit (that would require something you can't do).

---

---

There's nothing abnormal about being afraid of going into an attic where blown insulation covers the rafters.  When blown insulation covers the floor, you have no way of knowing if there's even a floor there.  If there's no floor, then one misstep and your foot punches through the ceiling drywall and you have an injury, a fire department rescue, a BIG mess, and an expensive repair bill.

- The correct course of action is to get a whole bunch of trash bags, a quality mask and glasses, and shovel all the blown insulation into the trash bags until the floor is easily observable.  Then create a floor using appropriate materials (quality plywood is my choice; stronger and lighter than OSB; if 4x8 sheets are unwieldy have the yard cut it to your rafter spacing typ. 16" or 24").  Then lay the floor as you advance into the attic, removing insulation as you go.  Then add a few lights at the apex, then do your work that you need to do.  Then put the insulation back over the new floor.  Do the entire floor so next time you're up there you never have to worry about if there's a floor here.

Comment: the way the basement was wired, i just paid a lot fixing it, it was, that is the electrician term, octopus junction box, power was coming in and was split all over the place, i had 1 junction box having 1(wire) power in and 7(wires) power out. i also had one with 1 in and 9 out, kind of a mess. I assume I have 2 octopus box in the attic, one for the left side and one for the right side of the picture. if lucky i could find where the neutral is not connected and fix at least this issue with that neutral. side note light switch and light only have 1 wire in them, same with the microwave outlet.

Comment: just to add to what @Harper-ReinstateMonica said ... always wear a hardhat in the attic if nails from shingles or from roof tiles are visible ... you should really wear one if the attic is unfinished, because you never know what might be sticking out

Comment: @Fredou isn't anything wrong with octopus wiring per se, as long as the work is proper and the box is big enough for the splices.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica i know, but that one (8 wires) was behind drywall without any access, I just found it again in my trash, i think i will keep it to remind me why i spent a few thousands rewiring the basement. This is what it looked like, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Flg7GclDmMA sadly the one with more wires, they removed the wire one by one. this one was found after. They just decided to remove it as-is.

Comment: @jsotola i need to find a friend that can go into the attic, i think i have claustrophobia, i tried once to go in, i just wasnt able, thanks for the tip ... i will make sure he/she have one

Answer (score 2):

> is that a dangerous way of connecting everything, is it a latent defect?

Absolutely it is dangerous, having unblalanced currents in a cable can cause inductive heating of the apertures the cable passes through. for this reason it is a code violation.

What you have drawn looks bad, there could be other faults lurking there too that would be revealed by photographs.